# transition scene sprite kit

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, transition, scene

Im having trouble transitioning to pre determined location on a different scene. (for example when Mario goes into the tunnel he returns to the original scene right where he left off) I was able to code a way to get to the next scene but node does not appear were I would like it to.

this is my code to transition to second Scene

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    _ = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == BodyType.cup.rawValue && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == BodyType.ball.rawValue) {

touchmain()


} else if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == BodyType.ball.rawValue && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == BodyType.cup.rawValue) {

touchmain()

}
}

    func touchmain() {

        let second = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")
        second?.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        self.view?.presentScene(second!, transition: SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.5))
    }
```

I would really appreciate it if you guys can help a young developer out. much love!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could go about this. The general gist of it is, just remember "Mario's" location before you leave the scene and pass it along to a property in the next scene. (or you could use delegation to get the info)

If the scenario is that he starts in SceneA(main level) transfers to SceneB(small money tunnel) and then returns to SceneA(main level) you could pass the location to SceneB and have a property in SceneB that stores where Mario was. Then when you transfer back to SceneA just pass the property back to a property in SceneA, and position Mario and SceneA accordingly

```
    func touchmain() {

        let marioPos: CGPoint = Mario.position

        let second = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")
        second.startingPos = marioPos
        second?.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        self.view?.presentScene(second!, transition: SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.5))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `userData` field on SKScene to remember the position:

Somewhere in the first scene init, do :

```
userData = [String : NSObject]()
```

Also, in your first scene, we want to override `didMove(to:SKView)` to set mario position based on your userdata :

```
override func didMove(to:SKView)
{
   super.didMove(to:to)
   if let position = self.userData["position"]
   {
      mario.position = position
   }
}
```

We then want to actually assign the user data when transitioning away from the scene:

```
func touchmain() {
        if let userData = self.userData
        {
            userData["marioPosition"] = mario.position
        }
        if let second = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")
        {
            second.scaleMode = self.scaleMode //I assume we do not want to change scaleMode between scenes
            second.userData = userData
            self.view?.presentScene(second, transition: SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.5))
        }
        else
        {
            print("Error creating Second scene")
        }
}
```

When we are coming back, we want to transfer the `userData` back to the first screen.  This is where the `didMove` that I mentioned earlier comes into play,  this will set the position of mario to previous location.

...  I do not see this code, so try and apply it to how ever you are doing it

```
func touchBackToFirst() {

        if let first = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")
        {
            first.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
            first.userData = userData
            self.view?.presentScene(first, transition: SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.5))
        }
        else
        {
            print("Error creating Firstscene")
        }
}
```